# Spring Cloud Dataflow httpclient.exactlyOneUrl error

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am have started working with Spring Cloud Dataflow on Apache Yarn.

I have created a stream which will send GET request to a REST API and send the response to a kafka broker.

In Yarn application log, I am seeing the below error:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Binding to target
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.httpclient.processor.HttpclientProcessorProperties@18317edc
>   failed:
>
> ```
> Property: httpclient.exactlyOneUrl
> Value: false
> Reason: Exactly one of 'url' or 'urlExpression' is required
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Update your application's configuration

**Sample Stream:**

```
stream create --definition "trigger --time-unit=SECONDS| httpclient --url='''http://<hostname>:8989/api/galileo?floorid=Shop%20Floor%201''' --http-method=GET  > :streamtest1" --name ingest_to_broker --deploy
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this the correct way of getting the response in Kafka topic?
2. Why am I getting httpclient.exactlyOneUrl error when I have already mentioned the URL?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what version of the app-starters you are using. There was some chatter on this subject in the past - see [spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/httpclient#3](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/httpclient/issues/3) for background.

It could be that the value that you're sending for `--url` is not accepted as a string. Try a simpler URL like the ones posted in the GitHub issue linked above.

Lastly, the YARN implementation of SCDF is at EOL mode. Please review the blog describing the [details and the dates](https://spring.io/blog/2018/11/01/project-update-spring-cloud-data-flow-for-apache-mesos-and-apache-yarn). We would recommend switching over to any of the other supported platform implementations.

Comment: Hi Sabby, Sorry for the late reply. We have switched over to SCDF local server and have been able to implement our streams successfully.